# how to handle directory names containing blanks globally?

Tags: pdftex

I tried this

```
\graphicspath{{/Volumes/MacHD2/'Messprojekte HD2'/Ensmad/Bericht/Bilder/}}
```

but it doesn't work. Okay, I could rename that directory, but would prefer not to do this.

I need a 'global' solution, I don't want to edit each of the 65 lines with `\inclegraphics` as you can see in the possible duplicate.

Comment: I would rename it. Then you spent less of your time searching for solutions to handle spaces. Beside this: `\usepackage{grffile}` works at least on windows in a current miktex/texlive, I tested it with `\graphicspath{{test with space/}}` (but the fact that I had to test shows you that I normally avoid spaces like the pest).

Comment: ;-)  okay, thanks a lot. If you all agree, I will delete this question